# React Hooks with Typescript - Property does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got the following provider/context...

```
interface Props {
  children: JSX.Element
}

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{auth, setAuth}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default AuthContext;
```

I'm using a custom hook to wrap this context usage like so:

```
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthProvider";

const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export default useAuth;
```

Then, I am trying to use the hook:

`const { setAuth } = useAuth();`

And I get an error on `setAuth` - Property setAuth does not exist on type {}.

This was some code I wrote in es6 that I am converting to TS but I am unsure how to resolve this particular issue.

Comment: Can you please try making the default value of the context `null`, like: `createContext<any>(null);`?

Comment: When you pass the empty object as the default value to `createContext` the type gets inferred as `{}`. You need to pass a generic to tell it what the type *actually* is.

Comment: @Thremulant that's unnecessary and misguided. Why should the type be `any`? OP knows the shape of the object, and `{}` is a more reasonable default value that `null`.

Comment: @JaredSmith got it. In that case it should be `createContext<IAuthContext>` where that new interface includes both  `auth` and `setAuth`

Comment: @Thremulant correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a generic parameter to your `createContext` function:

```
import { useState, createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

interface Auth {
  // The properties you expect on the `auth` variable
}

interface AuthContextInterface {
  auth: Auth
  setAuth: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Auth>>
}
```

With TypeScript, you're also expected to provide an initial value that matches the AuthContextInterface type, which can either be a set of default values or just `undefined!` to tell TypeScript you're sure that you'll override it later:

```
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextInterface>({
  auth: { /* an initial value for auth */ },
  setAuth: () => {}
});
```

Comment: Got me mostly where I needed to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you can provide an appropriate default value to the createContext function that includes both an auth object and a setAuth function. For example:

```
const AuthContext = createContext({
  auth: {},
  setAuth: (auth: any) => {}
});
```

This should allow you to destructure the setAuth function from the value returned by the useAuth hook without getting an error.

Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

As sometimes I don't have the initial value of the context, I'd suggest:

```js
interface IAuthContext {
  auth: IAuth // Whatever you need to add here
  setAuth: (auth: IAuth) => void
}
const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext | null>(null);
```